# How can I get the timestamp at which a row was loaded?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to find the epoch time at which a certain row was loaded, so that I can pick out appropriate table decorators for fetching other events loaded in close proximity. How can I query this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no automatically created column that holds the row time of creation - but you could certainly add one while loading data.

Comment: BigQuery internal feature request added.

Comment: +1 to this feature request.